# Find common field in records in Node.js + PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a Postgres table that records which users are now in which chatroom.

It has two columns - "chatRoomId" and "userId".

So assuming I have records like this:

```
chatRoomX, A
chatRoomX, B
chatRoomY, B
chatRoomY, C
chatRoomY, D
```

(That means user A,B in chatRoomX. Users B,C,D in chatRoomY)

Now, given an array of ["A","B"], I need a SQL query that can determine which chatroom they are now in - the query should respond with "chatRoomX".

So far this is what I have got:

```
client.query('SELECT chatRoomId FROM tableName WHERE 
 userId = $1 INTERSECT SELECT chatRoomId FROM tableName WHERE
 userId = $2', ["A","B"], function(err, results, done) { ... }
```

This query can successfully responds to me with "chatRoomX". But as you can see this query is hard coded and thus I need a better SQL that should work for an input array of users id with variable length.

Any ideas?

Comment: not the answer you are looking for, but why don't you create a table with two fields: `room_name` and `users` that can hold for example `chatRoomX` and `A,B`?

Comment: Hi TheBronx, I have considered that too. Doing that will save a lot of rows. But I thought appending usersIds in a string like that may introduce me problems in future. For example, now if A goes into chatRoomX, I can run one SQL query to insert this simple row "chatRoomX,A" if that row doesn't already exist. But using string based, I may need two SQL, one to first get the string of users in chatRoomX, second SQL to update that string... anyway I might still change to this logic if no good answer. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use PostgreSQL array logic to check if the array [A,B] is contained inside the array formed by all the people in a given chatroom.

Example:

```
SELECT ARRAY['A','B'] <@
       ARRAY(SELECT userId FROM tableName WHERE chatRoomId='chatRoomX')
```

This will return a single boolean result (`t` or `f`), true if the two persons are in the chatroom and false otherwise.

`<@` means "is contained by" for arrays. See [Array Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) in postgres documentation.

EDIT: assuming the query should retrieve all the `chatRoomId` in which A and B are simultaneously present, this could be written as:

```
  SELECT chatRoomId FROM
   (SELECT chatRoomId, array_agg(userId) AS a
     FROM tableName 
     GROUP BY userId) s
   WHERE ARRAY['A','B'] <@ s.a;
```

Comment: HI Daniel, thanks but i cannot hardcode chatRoomX in the logic. chatRoomX should be the answer...

Comment: @dunforget: then rewrite your question. Currently it's _I need a SQL query that can determine that these two persons are now in "chatRoomX"_ and the SQL query above is precisely the answer to that question.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks it works! But I noticed that I have to change the where clause to WHERE ARRAY['A','B'] <@ s.a AND s.a <@ ARRAY['A','B'] to make sure it wont return me another chatRoomZ when chatRoomZ has A,B,C in it.